# Run cmake function or add_custom_command only once

Tags: cmake

I have a ugly solution for copying .dlls to a bin folder that uses `add_custom_command`.
It works but in parallel build I am sometimes getting

> Error copying directory from

My guess(I can not know since [CMake will not tell me](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/3768) what failed) is that because calls to copy are done at same time so filesystem error occur.

Is there a way in cmake to specify that only first invocation of function or add_custom_command should run?

If it matters this is my copy dlls logic(every target needing those dlls calls the function with itself as argument):

```
 function(copyBla projectName)
     add_custom_command(TARGET ${projectName} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${SDK_PATH}/Bla/${BLA_VERSION}/x64/bin ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIGURATION>)
  endfunction()
```

P.S.
I do not want to limit myself to just one target calling `copyBla` since that is fragile(other targets depend on this target just because they want to use same dlls).

Comment: If you want your command to run once during every build, then use `add_custom_target(ALL COMMAND ...)`. A command created as **build event** flow of `add_custom_command` (with `TARGET` as the first argument) becomes **part of the command** which builds the target itself. Neither CMake nor a build system has no control over that part, so it cannot check whether it is called once or more times.

Comment: it may be worth changing the title of your post so others users can find this easier btw

Answer (score 1):

I think they fixed this pretty well in 3.21

$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:tgt>
New in version 3.21.

List of DLLs that the target depends on at runtime. This is determined by the locations of all the SHARED and MODULE targets in the target's transitive dependencies. Using this generator expression on targets other than executables, SHARED libraries, and MODULE libraries is an error. On non-DLL platforms, it evaluates to an empty string.

This generator expression can be used to copy all of the DLLs that a target depends on into its output directory in a POST_BUILD custom command. For example:

```
find_package(foo CONFIG REQUIRED) # package generated by install(EXPORT)

add_executable(exe main.c)
target_link_libraries(exe PRIVATE foo::foo foo::bar)
add_custom_command(TARGET exe POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:exe> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:exe>
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)
```

Note Imported Targets are supported only if they know the location of their .dll files. An imported SHARED or MODULE library must have IMPORTED_LOCATION set to its .dll file. See the add_library imported libraries section for details. Many Find Modules produce imported targets with the UNKNOWN type and therefore will be ignored.

Link to [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html?highlight=target_runtime_dlls%20tgt#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS) as requested

Comment: to be clear my post is just a copy paste of the official cmake docs

Comment: You could post a link to said docs.

Comment: not sure if it will work since it will require me writing some cmake(and that never ends well) but great find, take my upvote :)

Comment: I can't get the custom command to work. It generates errors in Visual Studio.